# Passing a generic ObservableCollection as CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I use many different ViewModels for objects, which I display in lists of checkboxes.
All subclasses (Giraffe and Elephant) inherit from the main class Mammal.
For each list of checkboxes there is a button to deselect them.
I would like to use a generic method that works with all subclasses.
I thought about passing the used ObservableCollection on to the command simply by clicking the button,
Unfortunately I can't dynamically recognize which subclass it is and cast it correctly.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Giraffes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Text}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Checked}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<Button Content="Clear" Command="{Binding ClearSelection}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Giraffes}" />
```

**MainViewModel**

```
private ICommand _clearSelection;
public ICommand ClearSelection
        {
            get
            {
                return _clearSelection ?? new RelayCommand((x) =>
                {

                    ObservableCollection<Giraffe> observableCollection = (ObservableCollection<Giraffe>) x;

                    foreach (var giraffe in giraffes)
                    {
                        giraffe.Checked = false;
                    }

                });
            }
        }
```

**ViewModels**

```
 public class MammalViewModel : BaseViewModel 
    {
        private bool _checked;

        public bool Checked
        {
            get => _checked;
            set
            {
                if (value == _checked) return;
                _checked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Checked");
            }
        }


        private string _text;
        public string Text
        {
            get => _text;
            set
            {
                if (value == _text) return;
                _text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }
    }

     public class GiraffeViewModel : MammalViewModel { }
     public class ElephantViewModel : MammalViewModel { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to deal with this is cast `ObservableCollection<T>` to `IList`, then cast every element of `IList` to the base class.

```
public ICommand ClearSelection
{
    get
    {
        return _clearSelection ?? new RelayCommand((x) =>
        {
            IList coll = (IList) x;

            foreach (var obj in coll)
            {
                ((MammalViewModel)obj).Checked = false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Or you can also cast `ObservableCollection<T>` to `IEnumerable` then use `Cast<TResult>` extension method to cast whole collection to `ObservableCollection<baseclass>`.

```
public ICommand ClearSelection
{
    get
    {
        return _clearSelection ?? new RelayCommand((x) =>
        {
            ObservableCollection<MammalViewModel> coll = ((IEnumerable)x).Cast<ObservableCollection<MammalViewModel>();

            foreach (var obj in coll)
            {
                obj.Checked = false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
 public ICommand ClearSelection
        {
            get
            {
                return _clearSelection ?? new RelayCommand((x) =>
                {
                    switch (x)
                    {
                        case ObservableCollection<GiraffeViewModel> giraffes:
                            DeCheckElements(giraffes);
                            break;
                        case ObservableCollection<ElephantViewModel> elephants:
                            DeCheckElements(elephants);
                            break;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```